# XCode 3 to XCode 4 Snapshot migration

Tags: xcode, version-control, migration, xcode4, snapshot

Hey wanted to ask if someone already tried to update the newly released XCode 4.
My problem is that all snapshots I made with XCode 3(.2.5) are no longer available in Xcode 4.
I would simply copy the `.sparseimage` but XCode 4 uses a new way to save the snapshots (each separate).

The same goes for color themes migration but the snapshot feature is more important.

//EDIT: completely forgot to mention that even all my archives got lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found one option:

1. make a backup of your current projects
2. open the `SnapshotRepository.sparseimage` from previous XCode version
3. there are subfolders for each project open one of them
4. copy the content from one subfolder (inside project snapshot folder) to its original position (e.g. `/myDevDir/projectYouWantToSnapshot/`)
5. open this project with XCode 4 and make a snapshot
6. optionally take the snapshot name from the `SnapshotArchive.plist` (in `.sparseimage`)
7. quit XCode 4
8. delete all files in your original project folder (e.g. `/myDevDir/projectYouWantToSnapshot/`)
9. repeat steps (4.) to (8.) till all snapshots are versioned

The only disadvantage I see (beside the manual work) is that the Date of snapshot is not correctly set. The best is to save the date (subfolders name) as description or name.

Comment: if someone has a better idea, please tell it, I will uncheck my answer